# $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$: A Complete Set of Representatives

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, modular-arithmetic

So, I'm letting ${\scr{A}}=\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ be a complete set of representatives (C.S.R.) for $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$. I'm considering all $b\in \mathbb{Z}$ and seeing if ${\scr{B}}=\{a_1+b, a_2+b, \dots, a_n+b\}$ is also a C.S.R.

My attempt follows:

For ${\scr{A}}=\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ to be a C.S.R. for $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ it must then be the case that for every $i,j$ with $1≤i<j≤m,a_i\not\equiv a_j \pmod{m}$. This means that $m\not\mid a_i-a_j$. Now, consider the set ${\scr{B}}=\{a_1+b, a_2+b, \dots, a_n+b\}$ and assume the opposite, namely that ${\scr{B}}$ is not a C.S.R. Then $a_i+b\equiv(a_j+b)\pmod{m}$, but this means that $m\mid (a_i+b-a_j-b)$ or $m\mid a_i-a_j$. This is a contradiction because $m\not\mid a_i-a_j$.

Comment: looks fine to me. Actually when you add b to the elements in A, you just get a permutation of the elements in the set after modding out by m.

Answer (score 2):

I think your attempt is good.  Here's another way to see it.  For any $b \in \mathbb{Z}$, the map $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ given by $x \mapsto x + \bar{b}$ is a bijection (with inverse $x \mapsto x - \bar{b}$).  If $\{a_1,\dots,a_m\}$ is a complete set of representatives of $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$, then $\{\bar a_1,\dots, \bar a_m\} = \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$.  Hence $\{\overline{a_1+b},\dots,\overline{a_m+b}\} = \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ and so $\{a_1+b,\dots,a_m+b\}$ is also a complete set of representatives.

Comment: What does your bar denote, just to be clear?

Comment: Bar denotes the image of an integer under the projection $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$.  In other words, $\bar c = c + m\mathbb{Z}$.